# Why calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) returns 10 instead of 12?

Tags: java

Why

```
calendarCurrent = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
calendarCurrent.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

returns 10 if it is 12 now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Month index starts from 0 not from 1 so it has to be 11 if it has returned 10 may be in US Locale it's not yet 11

Comment: Talk about "too localized" :)

Answer (score 2):

Months are  zero based (an unfortunate design decision, IMHO) so 0 means January and 10 means November. It's December 1 here, but it might still be November 30 in some time zones.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested it and it returns 11, which is december as months are in `[0, 11]`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29) :

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is
>   0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Everything is fine. You probably tested it a little before midnight or in a non US timezone, no ?

Comment: It has been december for 1 hour 14 minutes in UTC-11 by now :P Must be screwed system clock or the code wasn't run recently